# Separate JSON response

Tags: php, unirest

I am getting a response using Unirest library, i need to separate the data, so that based on that data i can call my next query. Here is full json response i am getting while using Unirest library

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($response->raw_body); echo '</pre>';

    {
  "status": "success",
  "images": [
    "http://www.example.com/12.jpg"
  ],
  "photos": [
    {
      "url": "http://www.example.com/12.jpg",
      "width": 205,
      "tags": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.978945010372561,
          "center": {
            "y": 64,
            "x": 129
          },
          "height": 79,
          "width": 79,
          "tid": "31337",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "smile_rating": 0.56,
              "smiling": true,
              "confidence": 0.56
            }
          ],
          "uids": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.35399999999999998,
              "prediction": "SE2",
              "uid": "SE2@SEA1"
            },
            {
              "confidence": 0.28999999999999998,
              "prediction": "SE1",
              "uid": "SE1@SEA1"
            },
            {
              "confidence": 0.16,
              "prediction": "Star1",
              "uid": "Star1@SEA1"
            },
            {
              "confidence": 0.106,
              "prediction": "SE3",
              "uid": "SE3@SEA1"
            },
            {
              "confidence": 0.037999999999999999,
              "prediction": "SE6",
              "uid": "SE6@SEA1"
            },
            {
              "confidence": 0.035000000000000003,
              "prediction": "SE5",
              "uid": "SE5@SEA1"
            },
            {
              "confidence": 0.017999999999999999,
              "prediction": "SE4",
              "uid": "SE4@SEA1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "height": 206
    }
  ]
}
```

What i am trying is to print like this

```
Confidence : 0.35399999999999998
Similar: Test2
```

Comment: What's the problem with JSON.parse ? Did you try something ?

Comment: I am using Unirest libray to get reponse print_r($response->raw_body);

Comment: They print like above mentioned code in question @Raptor

Comment: is this really tthe result of print_r? looks like invalid JSON string, its missing an enclosing `{ }`

Comment: I put some part of response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, provided it is a valid JSON string, just use a simple `json_decode()` with `true` flag so that it returns an array. Example:

```
$data = json_decode($response->raw_body, true);
$i = 0;
foreach($data['photos'][0]['tags'][0]['uids'] as $value) {
    if($i == 5) break;
    echo 'Confidence: ' . $value['confidence'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Similar: ' . $value['prediction'] . '<br/><br/>';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Undefined index: uids &  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Zack i made a revision check again accordingly

Comment: Can you example what this line is doing
$data['photos'][0]['tags'][0]['uids'] for future learning

Comment: @Zack basically what happened is from that JSON string, it is converted into a PHP array. since you want the `uids` values, you need to go to that index which is `$data['photos'][0]['tags'][0]['uids']`. and then foreach content of that array loop and print. thats about it

Comment: Can i limit the number of results in foreach, i want first 5

Comment: @Zack just add a counter if its 5 then break the loop

Comment: Done with that, one last question before you become rude to me :) Is there any possibility that i echo results with out foreach, i want to query db for image based on similarity result, confuse how i out mysql query in foreach or somewhere out of for each

Comment: @Zack no reason for me to be rude. don't try to hardcode each 5 values, just use the mysql query inside the foreach loop, anyway its getting off topic and broad.

Answer (score 0):

The release of [Unirest 2.0](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php/releases/tag/2.0.0) had many improvements including ability to set [custom JSON decode flags](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php#custom-json-decode-flags)

this gives you more control over the response body type parsing method (json_decode)

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of unirest-php and I work at Mashape.*